# Is there evidence to suggest movement of a pre-modern people group from South America to New Caledonia?

Tags: pacific-islanders

Recently we toured the New Calendonia culture centre. Our guide pointed to this marking on a rock, and said:

> My wife did a Masters in History in Canberra, and other experts have found rocks with the same markings in Colorado and South America.

[image]

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest movement of a pre-modern people group from South America to New Caledonia?**

Comment: There is evidence for some type of communication between South America and the islands in the pacific ocean in form of sweet potato: http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2013/01/22/169980441/how-the-sweet-potato-crossed-the-pacific-before-columbus . But I suppose it must have been polynesians who have travelled to South America and traded.

Comment: Haha your story reminds me of Thor Heyerdahl's, who was a Norwegian adventurer/anthropologist, who noticed similar designs and carvings in Polynesia and South America.

He developed a theory that people sailed from South America to populate Polynesia. He recreated the journey himself on a balsa wood raft in 1947. 

Apart from Heyerdahl proving one could recreate the journey, there was little evidence to support his theory until 2011 where DNA researchers proved that Polynesians did have some (8%) Native American DNA. This showed there was at least some contact.

Comment: "Kon Tiki" Great book, highly recommended. Obviously there are many interesting examples of Viking Settlements in Canadian North America...and claims Vikings made it all the way to the Mississippi actually.  The History of the MesoAmerican Civilizations still has yet to be written I might add. Sailing off the Coast of West Africa and ending up in the Caribbean is not that complicated. Winding up in North America however from there in fact was though.